# R: dbplyr: postgres: How to create an index on a table

Tags: r, postgresql, dbplyr

A user has a large table (3+ billion  rows).
To speed up queries for the next few months, an index on the remote database must be created.

Assuming there is a connection called `conn` - what is the best way to create an index and make it persist after disconnection from the database.

e.g.,

```
library(DBI)
sql<-'CREATE INDEX idx_pmid ON medcit  (pmid ASC);'
dbExecute(conn,sql)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

The code above seem to work but how can the index be somehow verified (make sure it truly exist and speeds up future queries)? In other words - how can a user check the existence of the index? Also, do I need to issue COMMIT command somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by *"verified"*? Existence and maintenance of indices can be found https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance.

Comment: *create an index and make it persist after disconnection from the database* ... why not save the index in the Postgres table **once** as it should have been in design of schema?

Comment: Why are you creating indexes at the application layer in R and not the database table level in Postgres?

Comment: @Parfait Because R is my general scripting language for everything and a single client for my project needs.

Comment: @userJT did you find some solution?

Answer (score 0):

To create an index on a table:

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "CREATE INDEX index_name ON public.db_name USING btree (variable_name)")
```